# mc: <ERROR> Unable to validate source - minio client

Tags: minio

i tried to download a file from my minio server using the following command, but it gave me error:

command:

```
mc cp host/host-db/2022-11-13-57a592e7-d979-40f6-b8e8-0d618964ee7e.gz .
```

error:

```
mc: <ERROR> Unable to validate source
```

**notes**:

1. this file is not empty
2. mc version : `RELEASE.2022-10-20T23-26-33Z`
3. this file is 103KiB
4. the command `mc ls host` works fine means it can connect to minio server.
5. im using minio client on windows : `Runtime: go1.19.2 windows/amd64`
6. the `host-db` bucket exists and the internet connection is OK.

what is the problem? how can i fix it?

**updates**:

- i cannot download anything from the minio server using minio client(mc).
- access permission is the following:

`Access permission for 'host/host-db' is 'private'`

- uploading files from local to s3 works but downloading files from s3 does not work.

Answer (score 1):

```
➜ mc cp play/tower/test-ilm.txt .
```

...ower/test-ilm.txt: 155 B / 155 B ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 125 B/s 1s

Please check the alias if it has been added properly.
`mc alias list host` and verify that the credentials and correct and API endpoint are correct